# In MonoDevelop how do you turn off the verbose comment generation when typing ///

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

This is more of a MonoDevelop question. I really like using '///' and getting the skeletal outline of comments like VisualStudio provides. But I hate having the extra filler text that is provided by default as it adds no real value (it just restates what I've already typed!). For the life of me, I cannot find the option to keep XML comment generation but not have the extra text. There was a bug report that has been fixed for this issue (https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=606222) but I didn't see where the option was to address.

All I want generated is:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bar"></param>
    public void Foo(string bar)
    {
    }
```

TL; DR;

**In MonoDevelop is there (and where is there) the option to turn off the verbose auto-generated comments, but keep the boilerplate /// comments for method headers?**

Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, I did confirm that you can type ///, **then** press your UNDO key combo and it will remove the extra verbiage. But that's a whole extra keystroke. I'm hoping that someone can tell me how to turn off that feature.

Comment: Up-voted. I'm using Doxygen which supports Markdown. Less XML in the world please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported. I'm pretty sure the solution to the complaints was that undo would have two steps so you could easily remove the autofilled values.

Adding options is a slippery slope. For example, you might want:

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bar"></param>
public void Foo(string bar)
{
}
```

But I might want

```
/// <summary></summary>
public void Foo(string bar)
{
}
```

And someone else might want

```
/// <summary></summary>
/// <param name="bar"></param>
public void Foo(string bar)
{
}
```

The options UI to support this would be very complex, and MD already has far too many options, so a strong case has to be made for every new option. The behaviour might not be perfect for everyone, but it's pretty good, and tweaking the generated docs is still much easier than typing them out from scratch.

However, the addin that generates the comments [is open-source](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.DocFood), so you could easily modify it however you want.

Comment: I understand. If I wasn't in the middle of building something new already, I'd take a look at what it would take to implement. I guess from my perspective, since most developers are coming from VS, the expectation would be that the commenting function would be a similar/identical experience. I have very strong feelings _against_ using GhostDoc type commenting system as no new information is added (how can it be). I can live with the undo--at least that gets me what I want for the comment template. Thanks.

Comment: That's a fair point, but the GhostDoc-like comments are really meant to be audited/edited into real comments. Even if you don't actually change them, the fact that you *decided* not to change them should mean that you checked they were correct, so they should always have some value.

Comment: So.... just got the last drop of MD and my undo compromise is gone (!)   :-(  . Before this I could type '///' and then undo and get the outline I wanted. Now when I do undo I'm just left with '///'.

Comment: Ouch, sounds like a regression. Could you file a bug?

Comment: Yeah, and it was closed as already fixed ... which I don't believe :-)  That may be why you didn't see it. Here is the link: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5087

Comment: "Undo" doesn't take me back to the "///", but to "//" instead. I really hate it when software tries to outsmart you and doesn't let you opt out. Way to be a stubborn smart ass, and an annoyance. I know what I prefer.

Comment: A new option was added to enable this, "Text Editor Options" -> "Generate additional undo steps for formatting", off by default.